# Why is File::listFiles faster than DirectoryStream - accepting only directories

Tags: java

So I "heard" that `DirectoryStream` introduced in Java 7 is faster than traditional methods of directory listing. However, this is not the case for me. It might have been faster for listing whole directory, but when filtering out files and only accepting folders, it takes far more time. For instance, these are the codes:

Using `File`:

```
ArrayList<File> tempArray = new ArrayList();
for (File file : someFile.listFiles()){
    if(!file.isDirectory())
        continue;
    tempArray.add(file);
}
```

Using `DirectoryStream`:

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = null;
try {
    stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
            public boolean accept(Path file) throws IOException {
                return Files.isDirectory(file);
            }
        });
} catch (IOException ex) {
}

ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList();
for (Path path : stream)
    files.add(path.toFile());
stream.close();
```

The second method (using DirectoryStream) is much more slower. I know both methods check each and every file to see if its directory. Or is it because `DirectoryStream`is synchronized (again, correct me if wrong)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the second case you're testing twice that the path is a directory. Further, you're actually defining a new class, which has a relatively large first-use cost.

Comment: sorry about that, actually this code is extracted from original code, so I must have accidentally added that check twice while manually writing again; in any case, I am not double checking for `ìsDirectory()`. And for your second point, are you talking about `new DirectoryStream.Filter`?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by you are using `filter` predicate in `DirectoryStream`, Stream with predicate is slower than collection. You can verify it by:

```
Stream.of(file.listFiles()).filter(f -> f.isDirectory()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Now, you can see, `DirectoryStream` is faster than `listFiles`.

So the root cause is not about `DirectoryStream` and `listFiles`, it's you are using `Stream` with `filter predicate`.